# weblogic & OHS - how to make my application available via the common external port

Tags: apache, proxy, weblogic, oracle-http-server

I have a application that is deployed on a weblogic server (12c).
Th application has a angular JS and a Rest endpoint part.
With the internal port & urls the application parts are working fine (both part of one ear deployment).
http://example.org:23777/MyApp-gui/index.html
http://example.org:23777/MyApp-rest/endpoint-1?para1=var1

What i now try with the OHS is to make it accessible via one root path + accessible from external, as it is only allowed to forward Port 8080.
For other applications that is working with the entry in the OHS (that is listening on 8080) configuration like this:

```
 <Location /MyApp>
  SetHandler weblogic-handler
  WLLogFile /opt/MyApp/MyApp.log
  Debug OFF
  WebLogicHost 127.0.0.1
  WebLogicPort 23777
  WLSocketTimeoutSecs 60
 </Location>
```

But I still cant access my application via the URLs I would expect:
http://example.org:8080/MyApp/MyApp-gui/index.html

Is there any further configuration I have to take care of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use for both (rest & gui) a separate location section in the apache conifiguraion:

```
 <Location /MyApp-rest>
  SetHandler weblogic-handler
  WLLogFile /opt/MyApp/MyApp-rest.log
  Debug OFF
  WebLogicHost 127.0.0.1
  WebLogicPort 23777
  WLSocketTimeoutSecs 60
 </Location>

 <Location /MyApp-gui>
  SetHandler weblogic-handler
  WLLogFile /opt/MyApp/MyApp-gui.log
  Debug OFF
  WebLogicHost 127.0.0.1
  WebLogicPort 23777
  WLSocketTimeoutSecs 60
 </Location>
```

So they should be available via the external addresses:
http://example.org:8080/MyApp-gui/index.html
http://example.org:8080/MyApp-rest/endpoint-1?para1=var1